# Проблема с запуском крестиков-ноликов

Tags: python, pygame

После запуска отображаются только правые три квадрата, остальное поле черное.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import pygame
import sys

def check_win(mas,sign):
    zeroes = 0
    for row in mas:
        zeroes+= row.count(0)
        if row.count(sign)==3:
            return sign
    for col in range(3):
        if mas[0][col]==sign and mas[1][col]==sign and mas[2][col]==sign:
            return sign
    if mas[0][0]==sign and mas[1][1]==sign and mas[2][2]==sign:
            return sign
    if mas[0][2]==sign and mas[1][1]==sign and mas[2][2]==sign:
            return sign
    if zeroes==0:
        return 'Piece'
    return False


pygame.init()
size_block = 100
margin = 15
width = height = size_block*3 + margin*4

size_window = (width,height)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size_window)
pygame.display.set_caption('Крестики нолики')

black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
mas = [ [0]*3 for i in range(3)]
query = 0
game_over = False
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and not game_over:
            x_mouse, y_mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            col = x_mouse // (size_block+margin)
            row = y_mouse // (size_block + margin)
            if mas[row][col] == 0:
                if query%2==0:
                    mas[row][col] = 'x'
                else:
                    mas[row][col] = 'o'
                query+=1
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            game_over = False
            mas = [[0] * 3 for i in range(3)]
            query=0
            screen.fill(black)

    if not game_over:
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                    if mas[row][col]=='x':
                        color = red
                    elif mas [row][col]=='o':
                        color = green
                    else:
                        color = white
            x = col*size_block + (col+1) *margin
            y = row * size_block + (row + 1) * margin
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x,y,size_block,size_block))
            if color==red:
                pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (x+5,y+5), (x+size_block-5,y+size_block-5), 3)
                pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (x+size_block-5,y+5), (x+5,y+size_block-5), 3)
            elif color == green:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (x+size_block//2,y+size_block//2),size_block//2-3,3)
    if (query-1) %2==0:
        game_over = check_win(mas,'x')
    else:
        game_over = check_win(mas,'o')

    if game_over:
        screen.fill(black)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('stxingkai', 80)
        text1 = font.render(game_over, True, white)
        text_rect = text1.get_rect()
        text_x = screen.get_width() / 2 - text_rect.width / 2
        text_y = screen.get_height() / 2 - text_rect.width / 2
        screen.blit(text1, [text_x, text_y])

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего блок кода после выставления цвета нужно подвинуть вправо, чтобы он попал во внутренний цикл (а заодно я и лишний сдвиг перед этим убрал):

```
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            if mas[row][col]=='x':
                color = red
            elif mas [row][col]=='o':
                color = green
            else:
                color = white

            # --- начиная отсюда я сдвинул блок кода вправо

            x = col*size_block + (col+1) *margin
            y = row * size_block + (row + 1) * margin
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x,y,size_block,size_block))
            if color==red:
                pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (x+5,y+5), (x+size_block-5,y+size_block-5), 3)
                pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (x+size_block-5,y+5), (x+5,y+size_block-5), 3)
            elif color == green:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (x+size_block//2,y+size_block//2),size_block//2-3,3)

            # --- досюда
```

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: нет, вышла ошибка с табуляцией: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Предыдущие `if/else` выровняли нормально тоже под 4 пробела после `for`? А то у вас там по 8 было.

Comment: File "ttt.py", line 68
    x = col*size_block + (col+1) *margin
                                       ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: @ВладиславКругляков этот ответ решает вашу проблему, просто используйте везде Tab`ы, а не 4 пробела

Comment: @ВладиславКругляков или нормальную IDE

Answer (score 1):

1. Ответ @CrazyElf решает проблему отрисовки, вам нужно просто использовать только Tab`ы вместо 4 пробелов для отступов.
2. У вас ошибка в коде вот в этом месте (вы скобки не поставили) :

```
    if (query-1) %2==0:
        game_over = check_win(mas,'x')
    else:
        game_over = check_win(mas,'o')
```

Чтобы ее исправить замените эту часть кода на:

```
    if query%2:
        game_over = check_win(mas,'x')
    else:
        game_over = check_win(mas,'o')
```

А лучше тернаркой:
`game_over = check_win(mas,'x') if (query % 2) else check_win(mas,'o')`

3. Ошибка в проверке второй диагонали. У вас так:
   `if mas[0][2]==sign and mas[1][1]==sign and mas[2][2]==sign`,
   а должно быть так
   `if mas[0][2]==sign and mas[1][1]==sign and mas[2][0]==sign`

Вот итоговый код, который у меня работает корректно:

```
import pygame
import sys

def check_win(mas, sign):
    zeroes = 0
    for row in mas:
        zeroes+= row.count(0)
        if row.count(sign)==3:
            return sign
    for col in range(3):
        if mas[0][col]==sign and mas[1][col]==sign and mas[2][col]==sign:
            return sign
    if mas[0][0]==sign and mas[1][1]==sign and mas[2][2]==sign:
            return sign
    if mas[0][2]==sign and mas[1][1]==sign and mas[2][0]==sign:
            return sign
    if zeroes==0:
        return 'Piece'
    return False


pygame.init()
size_block = 100
margin = 15
width = height = size_block*3 + margin*4

size_window = (width, height)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size_window)
pygame.display.set_caption('Крестики нолики')

black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
mas = [[0]*3 for i in range(3)]
query = 0
game_over = False

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and not game_over:
            x_mouse, y_mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            col = x_mouse // (size_block+margin)
            row = y_mouse // (size_block + margin)
            if mas[row][col] == 0:
                if query%2==0:
                    mas[row][col] = 'x'
                else:
                    mas[row][col] = 'o'
                query+=1
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            game_over = False
            mas = [[0] * 3 for i in range(3)]
            query=0
            screen.fill(black)

    if not game_over:
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                if mas[row][col]=='x':
                    color = red
                elif mas [row][col]=='o':
                    color = green
                else:
                    color = white
                x = col*size_block + (col+1)*margin
                y = row*size_block + (row+1)*margin
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x, y, size_block,size_block))
                if color==red:
                    pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (x+5,y+5), (x+size_block-5,y+size_block-5), 3)
                    pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (x+size_block-5,y+5), (x+5,y+size_block-5), 3)
                elif color == green:
                    pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (x+size_block//2,y+size_block//2),size_block//2-3,3)
                

    game_over = check_win(mas,'x') if (query%2) else check_win(mas,'o')

    if game_over:
        screen.fill(black)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('stxingkai', 80)
        text1 = font.render(game_over, True, white)
        text_rect = text1.get_rect()
        text_x = screen.get_width() / 2 - text_rect.width / 2
        text_y = screen.get_height() / 2 - text_rect.width / 2
        screen.blit(text1, [text_x, text_y])

    pygame.display.update()
```